# PHP check database for user ID

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database

I'm sending data to a php doc with jquery ajax. The first check (**$check_user_exists**) on the user's inputs is to see if there's an account under the same **$email**. I've tried writing a function before the if statement but that didn't work either.

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in C:\xampp\htdocs\workflow\ajax\register.php on line 8

Thanks ahead of time! Here's the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['role']) && isset($_POST['pw'])){
    $email = strtolower($_POST['email']);
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $pw = crypt($_POST['pw'], md5($email));
    $role = $_POST['role'];
    $check_user_exists = return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '$email.'"), 0)==1) ? true : false;
    if($check_user_exists === true){
        echo 'Our records show an account already exists under this email.';
    }
```

Comment: your userid is the email?

Comment: Using [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) would cut down your code by no less than 30%.

Comment: "Didn't work" is not good enough. Explain what the problem is.

Comment: `mysql_result()` returns the contents of the `user_id` field. Since your user IDs are apparently their email, not an identifier number, it will never be `== 1`.

Comment: **I'll be that guy:** Why would you even group up your query statements like that?

Comment: Also, when you use `return`, you return from the function, so the `if` statement will never execute. But I don't think it's valid syntax to have `return` after `=`, so you're probably getting a Parse Error.

Comment: Edited my post to include the error I'm getting. I'm new to php so I don't know the best approach for this kind of check. Definitely open to suggestions!

Comment: Plus, this `user_id = '$email.'")` should be either `user_id = '$email'")` or `user_id = '".$email."'")`

Comment: Fred ii, thanks for catching that error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['email']));
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$pw = crypt($_POST['pw'], md5($email));
$role = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['role']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$check_user_exists = $row['count'];
if ($check_user_exists > 0){
    echo 'Our records show an account already exists under this email.';
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (user_id, firstname, lastname, pw, role)
                 VALUES ('$email', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$pw', '$role')") or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'User added successfully.';
}
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, looks like it works in the sense that it doesn't add any new entries but it doesn't echo the error message. I forgot to mention that my database is called 'workflow' and it's hosted on localhost. so I added a select db statement, but it still doesn't work

Comment: You had an extra `.` after `$email` in the query. I've added the code to add the new entry. One of the two messages should be echoed.